# using ng-views in PhoneGap getting Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I am trying to get ng-views to work in android phoneapp app. I get the following
error when I trying to navigate to one of the views via hyperlink.

"Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

I have tried modifying the the cordova,xml in the res folder with no luck.

From

```
 <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->
```

To

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

Any advice is appreciated, below is the code.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="AngApp">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Minimal AppLaud App</title>

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="app.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var onDeviceReady = function() {

           $.support.cors = true;
           $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;

           // The message from the service is appearing, so Angular seems 
           // to be working fine without having to bootstrap it.
           //angular.bootstrap(document, ['AngApp']);
        };

        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
        }   
</script>  

  </head>
  <body onload="init();" id="stage" class="theme">
    <h2>Angular App</h2><br/>
    <a href="#/">View1</a>
    <a href="#/view">View2</a>
    <hr/>
    <div data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">    
        <p>{{Message}}</p>    

        <input type="text" data-ng-model="Message"/>

    </div>
    <hr/>

    <div data-ng-view></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

APP.JS:

```
var angApp = angular.module('AngApp',[]);

angApp.config(function ($compileProvider){
    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
});

angApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        controller: TestCtrl1,
        templateUrl: 'view1.html'
    })
    .when('/view', {
        controller: TestCtrl2,
        templateUrl: 'view2.html'
    });
});


angApp.factory('myService',function(){

    return 'I am a service';

});

function MainCtrl($scope, myService){

    $scope.Message = 'This is the main controller. '+ myService;
}

function TestCtrl1($scope){

    $scope.Message = 'This is controller 1.';
}

function TestCtrl2($scope){

    $scope.Message = 'This is controller 2.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a # sign there in href="#/view".

Comment: Thanks. Inserted it but still have the same issue.